# Reading space separated numbers from a file

Tags: java, file

I'm on my winter break and trying to get my Java skills back up to snuff so I am working on some random projects I've found on codeeval.  I'm having trouble opening a file in java doing the fizzbuzz program.  I have the actual fizzbuzz logic part down and working just fine, but opening the file is proving problematic.

So presumably, a file is going to be opened as an argument to the main method; said file will contain at least 1 line; each line contains 3 numbers separated by a space.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int a, b, c;        
    String file_path = args[0];

    // how to open and read the file into a,b,c here?

    buzzTheFizz(a, b, c);

}
```

Comment: Yes, but where is the problem? "Opening is problematic" - a file isn't Pandora's box - so what do you mean?

Comment: I hope you know, that the variables `a`, `b` and `c` will always be `0` when you pass them to `buzzTheFizz`.

Comment: @Tom You jump ahead :-)

Comment: Provide code for `openFile()` and `buzzTheFizz()` method and specify your issue in clear words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) like so;

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
a = sc.nextInt();
b = sc.nextInt();
c = sc.nextInt();
```

By default scanner uses whitespace and newline as seperators, just what you want.

Comment: Probably needs a loop - there'll be as many lines in the file as there are bubbles in the Fizz.

Comment: no idea what a fizz bubble is. I am just answering how to read 3 numbers.

Comment: A Fizz is a mixed drink, always with the addition of carbonated water. A bubble is the round thing raising up from the bottom. - In the Q: "at least one line".

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file_path));
    while( scanner.hasNextInt() ){
      int a = scanner.nextInt();
      int b = scanner.nextInt();
      int c = scanner.nextInt();
      buzzTheFizz( a, b, c);
    }
} catch( IOException ioe ){
    // error message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop it reads the whole file, have fun:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    String file_path = args[0];

    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(file_path));

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            a = sc.nextInt();
            b = sc.nextInt();
            c = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("a: " + a + ", b: " + b + ", c: " + c);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
}
```